# extract characters between two commas?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with ~ 3 million rows, here is the first few lines of my file:

```
head out.txt
    NA
    NA
    NA
    NA
    NA
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753,gene85754
    gene85752,gene85753,gene85754
    gene85752,gene85753,gene85754
    gene85752,gene85753,gene85754
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752,gene85753
    gene85752
    gene85752
```

For those rows that are separated by ",", I want to keep everything after the first comma and before the second comma.
This is my desired output:

```
outgood.txt
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85752
gene85752
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `cut` prints non-delimited lines by default the following works

```
cut -f2 -d, file
```

Comment: It's nice when someone remember the little quirks of standard tools.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, 'NF > 1 { $1 = $2 } { print $1 }' file
```

This uses `awk` to parse the file as lines consisting of comma-delimited fields.

The code detects when there is more than a single field on a line, and when there is, the first field is replaced by the second field.  The first field, either unmodified or modified by the conditional code, is then printed.

Comment: With a big file, this would probably be faster: `awk -F, '{print(NF>1 ? $2 : $1)}'` -- since you won't have to rewrite $0

Comment: @glennjackman Well, the `cut` solution would be even faster in any case.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, 'NF == 1 {print $1}
         NF > 1 { print $2}' filename
```

This will print just the first string if there is no comma, second string if there is one or more comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Perl` as follows.

**Command-line:**

```
$ perl -F, -pale '$_ = $F[1] // $_' out.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `-p` will read records line-by-line AND autoprint before going in to read the next or eof.
- `-l` makes `IRS = ORS = "\n"`
- `-F,` makes `FS` a comma.
- `-a` splits each record `$_` on the field separator, in our case a comma, and goes ahead and stores the fields so generated in the array `@F`, which is zero-indexed.
- `-e` implies, what follows it is the `Perl` code, which shall be gets applied to each record.
- `$_ = $F[1] // $_` expression reads as follows: if the 2nd field `$F[1]` isn't defined, use the current record `$_`. And then the result of this expression is assigned to the current record `$_`.
- owing to the `-p` switch of `perl` being in use, before the new record is read in, the current record is taken to `stdout`.

**Result:**

```
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85753
gene85752
gene85752
```

You may also do it with the GNU version of the `sed` editor as shown below:

```
$ sed -ne '
    s/,/\n/
    s/.*\n//
    s/,/\n/
    P
' out.txt
```